# Delete multiple rows error

Tags: mysql

I have a query to delete some rows, whats wrong with it?

```
DELETE FROM table1, table2, table3
WHERE table1.id = table2.id
AND table2.id = table3.id
AND table1.id = 10
```

please help with query

Comment: If you want to delete from all three tables, change the first line of your query to `DELETE table1, table2, table3 FROM  table1, table2, table3` and follow with the rest of your query. The docs give examples [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) - on the page search for "You can specify multiple tables" to find the section on multi-table delete syntax.

Comment: not working with `DELETE table1, table2, table3 FROM table1, table2, table3`

Comment: Please define "not working".

Answer (score 0):

With this query it should work.

```
DELETE t1, t2, t3 FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
INNER JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.id = t3.id
WHERE t1.id = 10
```

I tested it local with this schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5be4/9

Details you can find in the socd: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: 6 tables (108 rows deleted) = 70 seconds :(( ! any faster idea?

Comment: We need more details about your database tables. Do you use indices? Why 6 tables, in your questions are only 3?! Please update your question with more details, so we can help you.