# Writing the SQL query based on 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I am really confused writing this SQL query, it might be easy but I still cannot come to the right solution.

Idea: Delete rows (foreign keys) from `TableA` based on `TableB`, if in `TableB` exist Primary Keys which match some other value within `TableB`.

For table `B` it should look like this:

```
SELECT Column1 
FROM TableB
WHERE Column2 = 'Value';
```

And then

Delete rows in `TableA` which match to values inside of `Column1` (`TableB`).

Comment: You have to join the table and delete it:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425235/delete-multiple-rows-error

Comment: You should decide which database you are using (MySQL or SQL Server) and tag the question appropriately.

Comment: Question edited. Thanks for shared links. I am checking them right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you need to match `ColumnX` in `TableA`:

```
DELETE FROM TableA 
WHERE ColumnX IN (SELECT Column1 
                  FROM TableB 
                  WHERE Column2 = 'Value');
```

Comment: Thanks for working solution, victor175! I thought close to you but still had some errors in my query.

Comment: if `column1` in `TableB`  is nullable, and has some null values this query will return unexpected results.

Comment: The query deletes records in `ColumnX` which are the same as ones in `Column1`. So records which are NULL in `ColumnX` will be deleted in this case. Not quite unexpected.

Comment: `IN` operator is translated to `Column = 'Value1' OR Column = 'Value2' OR ...` and so on.... When there is a NULL value being returned by the inner query it gets translated to `Column = NULL`, which is an invalid expression in sql server.

Answer (score 1):

`IN` operator is good when you have hard coded values in `IN` operator like `where SomeCoumn IN ('value1', 'Value2')`

Or you are checking against a Primary key column like `WHERE SomeColumn IN (select PK_Column from SomeTable)`

Because in either of the above cases you will not have a *NULL* value inside your *IN* operator.

Null values inside `IN` operator brings back unexpected results.

A better option would be to use Exists operator... something like....

```
DELETE FROM TableA 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
               FROM TableB 
               WHERE TableA.ColumnX = TableB.Column1
                AND TableB.Column2 = 'Value'
            );
```